# Ajax upload using ajax. XMLHttpRequest cannot load error

Tags: ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing a Youtube API that can upload a video from my website to the users Youtube Acount. 
I manage to upload a video. but when i try to use ajax in uploading the video this error shows up.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/action/FormDataUpload/AIwbFAS4G0YorrPAcesbCbdDeRnONQ6PJsamMbLu2_KU8EZm_8jjn-Eq7C7oHPRMnbFwoZlMUuJNYOP2IVzJ1J0OL1nkC3a8kg?nexturl=https://mysitewebsite.com/test/.
>   Origin http://mysitewebsite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I use this http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/ jquery upload scripts for my fancy upload.

Thank you in advance for any answer you could give me to fix this error.
by the way. I am developing this is localhost.

Comment: Problem can be in exectly in 'localhost'. In this case a huge developers are able lock youtube with requests. So you need check security setting for uploading video and if this allow to uploud from localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uploads.gdata.youtube.com doesn't support CORS yet. It will soon, hopefully.

In the meantime, you could follow this example, which accomplishes an upload using a standard HTML form submission: http://gdata-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata/youtube_upload_cors.html